# Displaying errors with Laravel Form validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel

I am learning Laravel. I am doing Form Validation at the moment. In the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation) it is said the variable $errors is flashed to the session and is always available. I get an exception because an undefined variable. I only pasted the sample code from the documentation:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Error message:

```
ErrorException in 318c473e4384f7c25db0019a770ee937b30041d1.php line 41: Undefined variable: errors (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\NightClubs\resources\views\add.blade.php)
```

This are the validation rules in the controller:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'youtube' => 'required|url',
        'coordinatex' => 'required|between:-180,180',
        'coordinatey' => 'required|between:-90,90',
        'nameofclub' => 'required'
]);
```

Comment: Please post full error message you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the group for routes where you want to use `$errors` variable:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // Your routes
    // Your routes
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer has helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have validation rules in your controller.

Try this in your view

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work, as I have already said the variable is not defined. Yes, I do have validation rules in my controller, I have since added them to my question.